# Creating 3D image model from 2D image using AR in Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I'm new to Augment Reality and not having a compatible device to run examples provided for [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar). I am having a few questions and want them to clear before going further as I'm getting clear about those through any mean. The app I'm working over is gonna perform the following task.

- Detect a logo from a product
- Create a 3D model of it using AR
- display the generated 3D model at the exact same surface
  Here is a sample image captured from a box. I want to display the **text** and **logo** in the 3D model.

[image]

**My Questions**

1. is it possible to display both logo and text as a 3D model or AR 
   supports images only?
2. Should I use **ARCore** or **OpenCV** or any other to do the task? which one is efficient regarding time and memory to implement?

Maybe it would be a discussion-based question but I am literally unable to find a solution for it. 
Thanks everyone!

Comment: So something like: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have ARCore supported device, you can try Vuforia + Unity instead. Vuforia also supports image recognition and overlay with AR. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khavGQ7Dy3c) for your use case.

If you still want to use ARCore, you should check out [Augmented Images](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images) feature. The challenge here if your logo has a good score to be able to work nicely for tracking and overlaying AR.
You can check image quality/score with [this tool](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/arcoreimg).

Comment: the tool you mentioned for image quality/score is just gonna work on Windows or Mac OS. Is there anything for Ubuntu?

Comment: It would work on Linux, here is it: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/tools/arcoreimg/linux